# How could I display the y-value of 2 different curves when clicked with Tkinter and Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to be able to click anywhere on the graph and a vertical line would appear along the x-value that was clicked. I wish to be able to display the values of each of the graph's curves at that x-value. I've made a diagram that shows what I mean.

[image]

I've been Googling how to do this, but haven't really found anything relevant to what I'm looking for. The only thing I can think to do is to store the coordinates where the user clicked their mouse pull the y-values at that x-value. I would then manually draw the line over the graph. I think this would work, but it's a lot messier than using a built-in function if such a function exists. Does Matplotlib have this capability?

Comment: Are you having trouble drawing the line, or finding the intersection points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any sort of built in method for achieving this functionality. Fortunately, it was not that difficult to make manually.

On your `FigureCanvasTkAgg` object you can call:

```
figurecanvas.callbacks.connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

You will also want to define a variable that stores the index of the line you will move around.

```
line_index = None
```

Doing this defines a behavior to occur when when the canvas is clicked. The `onclick` method must have only one parameter, which is the click event.

```
 def onclick(event):
        if event.xdata and event.ydata:  # This checks if click is outside the chart or not

            # line_index is initially None, so we need to check if there is a
            # previous line to delete
            if line_index:  
                del self.ax0.lines[line_index]  # this removes the previous line

            self.line = self.ax0.axvline(x=event.xdata)  # draw a new line where clicked
            self.ax0.figure.canvas.draw()  # update the canvas
            line_index = len(axis.lines) - 1  # store index of the line for future deletion
```

In the `onclick` method, you can also include functionality that outputs the value of a line at the point clicked. You can access the x-value of the location clicked with `event.xdata`. This can be used in conjunction with the data you are graphing to output the y-value at the point clicked.